# get Width and height of image php from imageCreateFromBMP($src)

Tags: php, image, height, width

I want to know the image width and height of an image from the return image using imageCreateFromBMP($src) rather than $src. How can i achieve this ?

```
$src = 'four.bmp'; //src of image
$im = imagecreatefrombmp($src); 
list($width, $height) = GetImageSize($im); // it doesnot work though it takes string 
echo 'Image width '.$width.'</br>';
echo 'Image height '.$height.'</br>';
```

Comment: `imagesx()` and `imagesy()` take an image resource

Comment: Thanks man ! write in the answer.. I will accept your answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`imagesx()` and `imagesy()` take an image resource

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagesx.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagesy.php

Example:

```
$src = 'four.bmp'; //src of image
$im = imagecreatefrombmp($src); 
$width = imagesx($im);
$height = imagesy($im);
echo 'Image width '.$width.'</br>';
echo 'Image height '.$height.'</br>';
```